# Guest users unable to fetch data from Microsoft Graph API? Returns a item not found response

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to verify if i got everything correctly configured on my side.

I have a user who is registered at **Tenant A** as a guest user in Azure AD, thats created on **Tenant B**. This graph api endpoint is currently fetching info from **Tenant A**. I've concented in both Tenant A and B as an global administrator and the account that im trying to fetch from, but still im unable to fetch any data for that user.

Ive only tried this endpoint that works fine with a memeber in Tenant A but not as a guest user.

Response for member:
[image]

Response for guest:
[image]

Only thing that differs in this request is the access token of course.
I feel like if it was 401 i would kind of get it but since it's 404 im not fetching anything specific just any site that the user has access to, like an empty response would be fine but 404 doesn't tell me much. Any idea what I'm missing here or haven't checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 404 is, because when you pass the Access Token of the Guest User in the authorization header, it must be connecting to the Home Tenant of the guest user. Since the resource doesn't exist in the Home Tenant of the guest user, it throws 404.

To confirm this, login to Graph Explorer using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer link, sign-in using Guest user and execute the GET call.

If it fails with 404, then use below link to access Graph Explorer. Notice the parameter tenant in the URL. By using this parameter you can specify which tenant you want to connect to and to avoid connecting to the home tenant by default.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com

Once this is confirmed to be the issue, you need to make sure the token is issued by the tenant that has the resource and not by the home tenant of the user.

For example, if you use below call, token will be issued by TenantA to the guest user.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_A.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=APP_ID_FROM_TENANT_A&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&state=1234&response_mode=fragment&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Note: To acquire token using above call, make sure below settings are configured:

1. Under Authentication blade of the app (whose client ID you specified in the above authentication call), the checkbox for **Access tokens (used for implicit flows)** is selected.
2. Under API permissions blade of the app, Directory.AccessAsUser.All and sites.read.all graph permissions are added and consented by the admin.
3. Under Authentication blade of the app, make sure the redirect URI is set as https://jwt.ms

Once you get the token using this method, use it in the authorization header of your GET call and you should no longer get 404.

Comment: Thank you for your long reply. Very helpful information. I've look thurley through this and went step by step. Step 1 and 2 is a Yes they are indeed concented and created. Step 3. Ive done and added jwt to the redirect. I went to the jwt page and took the access token but still i got the same error. Can you verify that it works for you?

Comment: I have tested it and it works for me.  If you are still getting 404, I suspect the problem is due to token issued by wrong tenant. In the decoded token at jwt.ms, which tenant do you see in the iss (issuer) claim? The token issued to guest users include iss and idp claims, where iss claim includes the guest tenant's and idp claim includes the home tenant of the guest user. Make sure both claims are present in the token.

Comment: I just checked. The guest user's iss from Tenant A and the idp is the home tenant aka Tenant B so everything looks correct there. What else could it be? :)

Comment: Instead of /sites?search=*, If you try the GET call with root or site-id (like, /sites/root or /sites/contoso.sharepoint.com) does that work? I have seen issues, where guests can't enumerate items but can query specific item.

Comment: Now when i concent as the guest user with the admin concent url that ive googled to get i can now iterate the list. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=myid&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://localhost:12345
but i havent concented to the whole organisation. Even though through the webb app i have concented i needed to do it with that url. I could iterate through the pages if i was added with full control on the root site the search=* works fine. Thank you for your help!